# Azure WebSites doesn't return response body for errors

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have the following configuration: Python TornadoWeb application deployed on Azure Web Sites. The application is actually REST API that returns JSON back. However... everything works fine if the response code is 200 but if the response code is anything like 50x or 40x the response doesn't contain any body (although there should still be JSON body with error details). Testing the same code locally directly to Tornado or via NGiNX works. Apparently, IIS filters the body but not really sure what settings to change in order to avoid this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to create a web.config and set the `customErrors` element appropriately. [These](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx) are the options. The web.config will need to reside in the root of ur deployed folder structure. Generally speaking one should not expose every single internal error detail with stack trace to users because they probably will not be able to understand it all and it will also give much information about ur system to a potential attacker. That is why I prefer short error messages as http response and the rest gets logged somewhere for later analysis.

Comment: The only problem with that is that Azure Web Sites overrides everything you do with the web.config during deployment from Visual Studio. The setting in web.config that I tried was` <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />` but it was completely wiped out.

Comment: Not sure that is true. We have a web app and a web.config that takes effect. Maybe try ftp deployment (no visual studio in between) to check if the problem actually can be solved with that web.config setting

Comment: Thanks Helikaon - logically this was my next step hit by another error - I am not able to configure Git deployment on the app. My next option was of course FTP but the the FTP traffic is blocked on the firewall :)

Comment: This is bad karma :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to refer to the sections [`WSGI Handler`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#wsgi-handler) and [`Web.config`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/#webconfig) of the doc "Configuring Python with Azure App Service Web Apps" to configure and code for your Python Tornado webapp as [Running Tornado apps on WSGI servers](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#running-tornado-apps-on-wsgi-servers).

If you created a Azure WebApp for Python, you can do the steps below.

1. Create a `web.config` file in the Kudu path `wwwroot`, then copy the configuration content from the section `Web.config`.
2. Create a `app.py` file in the Kudu path `wwwroot`, then code as the section `WSGI Handler`.
3. Try to start and access the webapp.
4. Recode the webapp using Tornado.

Comment: Yes, all this is done as per the links that you provided but the errors are still filtered.