# Migrate Python Tornado application to Azure

Tags: python, linux, azure, tornado, azure-connect

Right now I'm having a Python application developed on Tornado framework.

I need to migrate it to Azure. The Back-end i will use is Clear-db as we have MySQL in On-premises.

Kindly suggest me how to migrate and host the Application on Azure.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way to migrate is to use Azure Web Apps. It supports different Python versions, WebSockets, etc, and you should be able to migrate almost (or at all) without changes. Take a look at [that tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/).

The second way would be to use Virtual Machines which is similar to the local server in terms of setting the needed software.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your comment.

The Azure Web App is supporting Django, Bottle, Flask. but im specifically looking for Tornado which is not available.

Right now I have suggested the Second way which you have mentioned. 

It would be great if I can know is there any other way to host the Python Tornado application

Comment: Yep, it may be not officially supported or there is no statement that is will work, but i saw it worked. Some folks here on SO managed it to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170442/azure-websites-doesnt-return-response-body-for-errors

Comment: It was nice and i got many things from ur links. We are using eclipse as IDE can I know how to do a direct deploy from eclipse to Azure Web Apps.

I'm using Pydev interpreter. As per the below link only CPython is being tested and working. Will PyDev will be supported and it can be used for Azure Web Apps.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/python-how-to-install/
Any links will be helpful.
Regards,

Sajiv